# JEST it.each([]) not expanding getter during test in NestJS

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I have shortened this down to a stand alone test, and I believe I am simply orchestrating the test incorrectly.  However, I cannot figure out why the service is not getting created properly when I can test the service directly, but not in an it.each().

I am trying to test a service's getter data using the it.each(), but it does not want to work within the Nest JS structure.

I have created a very simple example of my problem.  My service is to be shared, so it is in a LibraryModule that is then imported where needed.  However, my problem is just testing the service itself.

LibraryModule

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MyService } from './my.service';

@Module({
    providers: [MyService],
    exports: [MyService],
})
export class LibraryModule {}
```

MyService (very basic, simple getter for the example)

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    public get Description(): string {
        return 'text';
    }
}
```

I then work with the generated spec file for the service that was initially generated by NestJS schematics.

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { LibraryModule } from '@LIBRARY/library.module';
import { MyService } from './my.service';

describe('test with new() - This works.', () => {
    const TestClass: MyService = new MyService();

    it('should be defined', () => {
        expect(TestClass).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should return the Description', () => {
        expect(TestClass.Description).not.toBeNull();
        expect(TestClass.Description).not.toBeUndefined();
        expect(TestClass.Description).toBe('text');
    });

    it.each([['Description', TestClass.Description, 'text']])(
        'should return the text for %s',
        (TestDescription: string, Actual: string, Expected: string) => {
            expect(Actual).not.toBeNull();
            expect(Actual).not.toBeUndefined();
            expect(Actual).toBe(Expected);
        }
    );
});
```

The above tests work, including the it.each().  However, I have the second set of tests using the NestJS testing framework to create the service.

```
describe('test with MyService', () => {
    let service: MyService;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            imports: [LibraryModule],
            providers: [MyService],
            exports: [MyService],
        }).compile();

        service = module.get<MyService>(MyService);
    });

    it('should be defined - Works', () => {
        expect(service).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should return the Description - Works', () => {
        expect(service.Description).not.toBeNull();
        expect(service.Description).not.toBeUndefined();
        expect(service.Description).toBe('text');
    });

    it.each([['Description', service.Description, 'text']])(
        'should return the text for %s - FAILS',
        (TestDescription: string, Actual: string, Expected: string) => {
            expect(Actual).not.toBeNull();
            expect(Actual).not.toBeUndefined();
            expect(Actual).toBe(Expected);
        }
    );
});
```

Directly using service.Description works, however using the service.Description in the it.each() gives an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Description' of undefined

54 |
> 55 |      it.each([['Description', service.Description, 'text']])(
     |                                       ^
56 |              'should return the text for %s',
57 |              (TestDescription: string, Actual: string, Expected: string) => {
58 |                      expect(Actual).not.toBeNull();
```

I do not understand why when I create the service it works with the it.each(), but then when I allow the NestJS tests to create it, the it.each() fails, but tests using it directly (service.Description) work.  This implies that the service is created, but I do not know why it will not work with the it.each()?

Comment: Do you have any errors higher up in your test log? Seems like the `beforeEach` is probably failing, which is why `service` is `undefined`

Comment: No errors. As I indicate, using the service.Description directlhy works. It is just when I try it from the it.each() that it does not, which is the strange part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a limitation of Jest, not something inherently related to Nest. If you use the following test

```js
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';

import { AppService } from './app.service';

describe('AppService', () => {
  let service: AppService;
  let dynamicValue: string;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const modRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [AppService],
    }).compile();
    service = modRef.get(AppService);
    dynamicValue = Math.random().toString();
  });

  it.each(['string', dynamicValue, 'another string'])('%s', () => {
    expect(service.getHello()).toBe('Hello World!');
  });
});
```

You'll get the output

```
PASS  src/app.service.spec.ts
  AppService
    ✓ string (48 ms)
    ✓ undefined (10 ms)
    ✓ another string (10 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.92 s
Ran all test suites matching /app.service/i
```

Which shows that values determined in the `beforeEach` are not available inside of `it.each`. The same goes for `beforeAll`. It works in your first test, because you create the test class before defining any of the tests or references to the tests, it's essentially a defined variable for the test suite, vs a declared one.

Comment: Thanks. Your example is very clear. I guess I can try to post something to the Jest team then to see if this is something they will address in the future.